# scikit-learn - making multilabel classification with svm.svc classifier, is it possible without probability=True?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, document-classification

I tried to achieve multilabel classification with Pipeline\onevsrest classifier in scikit-learn. Code is below, but let me mention first that I construct my multilabel examples from a pandas dataframe.

Code is below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileIn, header = 0, encoding='utf-8-sig')
rows = random.sample(df.index, int(len(df) * 0.9))

work = df.ix[rows]

work_test = df.drop(rows)

X_train = []

y_train = []

X_test = []

y_test = []
for i in work[[i for i in list(work.columns.values) if i.startswith('Change')]].values:
    X_train.append(','.join(i.T.tolist()))

X_train = np.array(X_train)

for i in work[[i for i in list(work.columns.values) if i.startswith('Corax')]].values:
    y_train.append(list(i))


for i in work_test[[i for i in list(work_test.columns.values) if i.startswith('Change')]].values:
    X_test.append(','.join(i.T.tolist()))

X_test = np.array(X_test)

for i in work_test[[i for i in list(work_test.columns.values) if i.startswith('Corax')]].values:
    y_test.append(list(i))


lb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()

Y = lb.fit_transform(y_train)

classifier = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf')))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)

predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

But the issue is that when you use this set of transformations: `CountVectorizer -> TfidfTransformer` you get a sparse matrix. The issue is that when you try to predict labels using OneVsRest classifier it looks for `decision_function` or `predict_proba` methods. `predict_proba` is not available on `svm.SVC` unless you specify `probability=True`. On the other hand, as I see in code, `decision_function` is not implemented for sparse matrices. Thus my code fails since none of these 2 required methods are available. But maybe I am doing something wrong? Is it possible to somehow achieve multilabel classification with `svm.SVC` without specifying `probability=True?` (doing this adds some significant overhead to classificator training), maybe by somehow forcing TfidfTransformer to output a dense matrix instead of sparse one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [well-known issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/73) and by now no easy solution exists.

You can use [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to "densify" your sparse data (by calling `.toarray`), but this can blow up memory consumption. You can do [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) (AFAIK, it's the only dimensionality reduction method that works with sparse data), but it can mess with your data so that SVM's performance would decrease.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. toarray method works for me (at least for now, I am not working with too big datasets, so I could use such methods to compare performance of different svm kernels and decide which one to use).

Comment: Unfortunately, densification is not working - when I add toarray into pipline: TfIdfTransformer.toarray() it still thinks that the output is sparse. Am I donint smth wrong?

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, it's hard to say without actual code.

Comment: @Barmalay.exe Everything is same as in original question, just the pipeline definition is changed to this: classifier = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer().toarray()),('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf')))])

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, are you sure you run new code? Because the code you provided is absolute nonsense: `TfidfTransformer` doesn't have `toarray` method and it throws `AttributeError` for me. You should write your own Transformer (as a class) implementing `transform` method (look for Pipeline documentation for details).

Comment: Lol, sorry, I have done the change to code file but forgot that I was running the compiled version and haven't rebuilt it. Yeah, it just have no .toarray method. Just wanted to clarify, my transformer class (its method transform) should just get an input from TfIdfTransofrmer (sparse matrix), and call toarray() on it and return the result? I mean, is calling toarray() on sparse matrix would work or I should write even my own densification method?

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, from my experience calling `.toarray` on sparse matrix works.